# cross-platform real time update for mobile phones

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, urbanairship.com

i'm looking for a way to sync items stored in a database among users 
so anyone of those users changes anything from his phone , the change will be reflected in the database and SYNC with all users related to him in real time
what's the best way to achieve the real time sync ? push notification ? is Urban airship what i'm looking for ?

Comment: what did you end up doing here?

Comment: i THINK i might use pubnub.com

Answer (score 1):

Syncing data well is often specific to your application and your data.  It's beyond the scope of an SO question but here's some thoughts if you implement your own ...

Some of the interesting design points are:

- Reliably getting a delta
- Dealing with conflicts
- How real time is real time?

**For reliably getting a delta**, be careful about relying on date time for distributed machines.  This post discussed some of those challenges and some alternatives.

[Can I Rely on the iOS Device Clock Being Correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198833/can-i-rely-on-the-ios-device-clock-being-correct)

Merging new entities is easy but if multiple folks are editing the same entity, you need to decide how to merge.  **For conflicts, you can in order of preference** (1) auto merge - come up with an algorithm that automatically merges the content without user intervention and ideally with no data loss (2) rely on the user to merge with an interface and (3) a form of auto-merge: last write wins.  There's also variations where you interleave the revisions - it's a form of last write wins but the revisions are maintained .  You can also auto merge at a field level of an entity if that's appropriate.  My post to the question above covers interleaving but it depends on what your data is.

**How real is real time?**  When syncing occasionally connected devices, the devices will getting farther and farther out of date and it takes time to catch up.  Consider batching sets of changes in the communication pattern to optimize but it will still not be real time.  Embrace that in the design - does the user see data animate into there current views as data is synchronized?

Architecturally, you'll likely want to expose your data in the cloud through REST services or SOAP web services since it's cross platform.  For multiple devices platforms, you'll likely end up porting the sync algorithm.  The best you could hope for is using something like Sqlite so you can share your devices database schema code and sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with Dan Grover's presentation, "Cross-Platform Data Synchronization": http://iphone2009.crowdvine.com/talk/presentation_file/5104/Grover_Syncing.pdf